# Firebase Firestore returns a promise in Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use some data from from Firestore. before it used to work, now in Vuetify I keep getting 'PENDING' if I try to access the $data.users

```
    export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    db.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        user.id = doc.id;
        this.users = user;
        console.log(user.documents.selfie.url); // Here the log return the value correctly
      });
    });
  },
  methods: {
    imageUrl(user) {
      console.log(user.documents.selfie.url); // Here the log return "Pending";
    },
```

Inside the template I run a `v-for (user, index) in users :key='index'`

ERROR:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'selfie' of undefined
```

Comment: before v-for check by v-if your data is set and use `user.documents.selfie.url || 'http://example.com/to/default.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be 100% sure without reproducing your problem, but I think the problem comes from the fact that the Promise returned by the asynchronous `get()` method is not yet [**fulfilled**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) when you call the `imageUrl()` method. This is why you get the `pending` value.

One possibility to solve that is to check as follows:

```
  methods: {
    imageUrl(user) {
      if (user) {
         console.log(user.documents.selfie.url);
      } else {
         //...
      }
    },
```

---

Also, is seems you want to populate the users Array with the docs from the `users` collection. You should do as follows:

```
  created() {
    db.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) => {
      let usersArray = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        user.id = doc.id;
        usersArray.push(user);
        console.log(user.documents.selfie.url); // Here the log return the value correctly
      });
      this.users = usersArray;
    });
  },
```

With your current code you assign the last user in the loop, not the list of users.

Comment: Thank you @renaud . It's getting better, at least now I dont break all the component. But what if the image doesn't load when the method is called? How could I solve that in the else block?

Comment: The best would be to call the method in the `then()` method in the created hook. You could also use a computed value with an `if then else` similar to the one above, and, as you mentioned you manage the case whe the image is not yet loaded in the else (e.g. showing a default image). You could also use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). It all depends on your exact case!